# How to Disable Spring Security Filters

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a situation where I have a RESTful service which is using a pre-authenticated token for authentication. I've implemented my own preAuth filter, and that's working great. My issue is that some requests sent to my service include BasicAuthorization which isn't for my application. (I wish they didn't, and they shouldn't, but they do and I can't control that.)

Now, it seems that Spring Security automatically makes a BasicAuthorization filter, but that filter is catching these irrelevant authentication headers, and then throwing the error:

```
Error 401 No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
```

So I want to turn off the filters I'm not using in Spring Security, but I can't figure out how. I know I could create dummy filters and replace the auto filters, or I could just delete all basic Auth headers before the application enters the filter chain, but those both seem like hacks.

When I looked in the spring security filter documentation I found [the part that shows you how to add a FilterChainProxy](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html), but it seems like I'm having to manually create all the beans for spring security that way. Specifically I got to the part where you need an AccessDecisionManager, but I thought that is what my

```
<http use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">

        <intercept-url pattern=[etc ...]
```

stuff was for, and I still want to use that. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Does the rest of your spring security config look like the Siteminder Example Configuration here? http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/preauth.html

Comment: Actually, I dont see the line <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="myFilter" /> in your <http> element...   hopefully adding that would make your filter get called first.

Comment: @samlewis It's actually not an issue of the pre-auth filter not being called first. It's an issue of a method that requires no authentication attempting to authenticate with an HttpBasicAuth auth header, and that throwing an exception, even though I don't want authentication on that method. An alternative solution would be to set that specific request as `security:none` (or however that is), and then put my pre-auth filter in front of the basic filter in the order, but again that sounds like a bit of a hack to me.

Comment: This is strange... I thought that BasicAuthenticationFilter is not registered if you don't have `<http auto-config="true">`. Is your example accurate?

Comment: After looking into it for a while, it turns out my example was incomplete. I was using [baeldung's spring security with a REST service guide](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/11/20/basic-and-digest-authentication-for-a-restful-service-with-spring-security-3-1/) and foolishly included `<http-basic />` from that. So ... sorry for the bad question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into it for a while, it turns out my example was incomplete. I was using baeldung's spring security with a REST service guide and foolishly included `<http-basic />` from that. So ... sorry for the bad question.